# How to set select box to default value on modal close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to clear the values in a modal when the modal is hidden. I am able to clear the value of a regular input field, but cannot get the select box to go back to the default value ('0' in this case).

This is my HTML / modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="entity_request_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="entity_request_modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Request to Add Business Entity</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <label>Business Name</label>
                    <input id="entity_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter business name..." name="entity_name" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Entity Type</label>
                    <select data-placeholder="Entity Type..." class="chosen-select" tabindex="-1" id="select_entity_type" name="select_entity_type">
                        <option value="0">Make a Selection</option>
                        <option value="3">Financial Institution</option>
                        <option value="14">College Institution</option>
                        <option value="13">Hospital or Clinic</option>
                        <option value="4">Internet Service Provider</option>
                        <option value="9">Cellular Provider</option>
                        <option value="10">Social Network</option>
                        <option value="7">Consumer Retailer</option>
                        <option value="8">Health Insurance Provider</option>
                        <option value="11">Auto Insurance Provider</option>
                        <option value="12">Home Insurance Provider</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="request_entity" class="btn btn-primary">
                    Save changes
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS / JQ:

```
$('#entity_request_modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('#entity_name').val('');
    $('#select_entity_type').val('0');
});
```

Again, '#entity_name' is being correctly reset, but '#select_entity_type' is not. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You May Set select option selectedIndex prop to 0;

```
$('#select_entity_type').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

Use like below.

```
$('#entity_request_modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
$('#entity_name').val('');
$('#select_entity_type').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});
```

Also Check The [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adhershmnair/bqc5xfch/2/).

Comment: I see it works in the fiddle, but it does not work in my code, what could the problem be?

Comment: Do you have latest jQuery library?  Or is there any error in console? Please Check.

Comment: For those wondering, the magic incantation to use with bootstrap-chosen is:         $(".chosen-select").val('').trigger("chosen:updated");